# Get more than one value from memcache with Ruby

Tags: ruby, memcached

I installed *memcache_client* GEM Ruby from http://seattlerb.rubyforge.org/memcache-client/

It's easy to get a single value:

```
cache.get('foo', 'bar')
```

How to get all values, starting with 'foo', for example foo_1, foo_2, foo_3, foo_* ?
Something like "SELECT * FROM foo", but for Memcached.

There will be about 10 000 "foo_n" entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a perfect solution, but look at the [`get_multi`](http://seattlerb.rubyforge.org/memcache-client/classes/MemCache.html#M000008) function:

```
keys = (1..10_000).map{ |n| "foo_#{n}" }
data = cache.get_multi(*keys)
```

Unfortunately memcached doesn't support regex key lookups, or [even let you get a list of all the keys](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#Can_I_iterate_the_items_of_the_memcached_server?) to process on your own.  One alternative would be to use [Redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/) which can [get a list of keys using a glob style pattern](http://code.google.com/p/redis/wiki/KeysCommand).

Comment: Yes that would be a problem if you don't know how many keys you need to lookup.  I have updated the answer with some thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Might want to look at Redis as an alternative to memcache. It supports lists, sets, sorted sets and hashes. http://code.google.com/p/redis/